# Reading from a file into a map which has key as integers and corresponding values as set

Tags: c++, c++11

I have entries in a txt file in the form of:

```
329881 100000005 100000125 100000145 
390876 100000667 100000745 100000288 100000395 100000392
289456 100034560 100000145 100000286 100000245
```

...
...

I want to read this txt file,structure by structure into a map which has 2 fields:

```
struct keyvaluestruct
{
    uint64_t _key;
    unordered_set<uint64_t> _set;
};
```

where key for 1st struct should be `329881` and the set should be `100000005` `100000125` `100000145`. Similarly, for the 2nd struct the key should be `390876` and values in the set should be `100000667` `100000745` `100000288` `100000395` `100000392`. These structures are then inserted into a map

```
map < uint64_t,unordered_set< uint64_t>> _mapstructs;
```

I am following the approach:

```
keyvaluestruct s1;

ifstream ifile('file.txt')

while(!ifile.eof())
{
    ifile>>key>>vset;

    s1._key = key;

    s1._set = vset;

    _mapstructs.insert(s1._key,s1._set);
}
```

Can anyone help me in correcting this approach or suggest an alternate approach?

Answer (score 1):

Something like the following would do:

```
#include <unordered_set>
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <cstdint>

struct Data
{
    uint64_t key;
    std::unordered_set<uint64_t> set;

    friend std::istream& operator>>(std::istream& s, Data& data) {
        std::string line;
        getline(s, line);
        std::istringstream s2(line);
        s2 >> data.key;
        data.set.clear();
        for(uint64_t element; s2 >> element;)
            data.set.insert(element);
        return s;
    }

    friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& s, Data const& data) {
        s << data.key;
        for(auto const& element : data.set)
            s << ' ' << element;
        return s;
    }
};

int main() {

    std::istringstream input("329881 100000005 100000125 100000145\n"
                             "390876 100000667 100000745 100000288 100000395 100000392\n"
                             "289456 100034560 100000145 100000286 100000245\n");
    Data data[3];
    for(auto& d : data)
        input >> d;

    for(auto& d : data)
        std::cout << d << '\n';
}
```

Comment: Thanks,but input is a file-name which is a n line .txt file

Comment: @Prastogi: You should be able to switch the example from istrstream to ifstream I believe...

Comment: @PRAS Replace `input` with `std::ifstream input("filename.txt")`.